# How to detect when a proxified function is used as a constructor?

Tags: javascript

Given this code:

```js
function MyClass() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
}

var handler = {
    get: function(obj, prop){
        console.log(prop);
        return obj[prop];
    }
};

var ProxifiedMyClass= new Proxy(MyClass, handler);

var myObj = new ProxifiedMyClass();
console.log(myObj);
```

The only information I have when I create an instance of `MyClass` via `ProxifiedMyClass`, is that the `prototype` has been accessed, which is not enough.

How can I safely assume that `MyClass` has been used as a `constructor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`construct()` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/construct) on Proxies.